# average query ORA-00936 error

Tags: sql, oracle, average, sqlplus

```
SQL> SELECT consignmentNo, VoyageNo, Weight
  2  (SELECT (AVG(WEIGHT) FROM consignment), AS AVERAGE,
  3  WHERE Weight = 650,
  4  FROM consignment;
(SELECT (AVG(WEIGHT) FROM consignment), AS AVERAGE,
 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

average weight for a particular ship, listing consignments for the particular ship also, unable to identify the error

Comment: Extra comma before `AS AVERAGE`. Should be `) AS AVERAGE` not `), AS AVERAGE`.  Also there's an extra open parenthesis in between `SELECT` and `AVG`

Comment: where weight = 650.... wouldn't that mean that the avg would be 650.... So are you wanting where the average weight is 650 or greater?  if so a having clause would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for `group by`?

```
SELECT VoyageNo, AVG(Weight)
FROM consignment
GROUP BY VoyageNo;
```

If you want the average *along with* the detailed information, you want a window function:

```
SELECT c.*, AVG(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY VoyageNo)
FROM consignment c;
```

This assumes that `VoyageNo` is what you mean by `ship`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `,` in your query (before `AS AVERAGE`) and you are missing a `,` after `Weight`. Also `from` and `where` is not in the right order. Try this:

```
SELECT consignmentNo, VoyageNo, Weight,
(SELECT (AVG(WEIGHT) FROM consignment) AS AVERAGE,
FROM consignment
WHERE Weight = 650;
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax either, where and from not in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
SELECT consignmentNo, VoyageNo, Weight, avg.AVERAGE 
FROM consignment CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT AVG(WEIGHT) AS AVERAGE FROM consignment) avg
WHERE Weight = 650;
```